# quandl installation is failing for numpy version 1.8

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, quandl

When I try to install qualdl , it is errors out with error

```
OSError: [Errno 1] Operation not permitted: '/tmp/pip-wMspId-uninstall/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/numpy-1.8.0rc1-py2.7.egg-info'
```

I am using python version = 2.7.10 , numpy version = '1.8.0rc1'  and pandas version  = '0.19.2'. I believe i am meeting all requirements for quandl. Please help me fix this problem.

Comment: can you try to run command with `sudo`

Comment: I did with sudo

Comment: Have you tried `ignore` flag ?

Comment: `--ignore-installed` add ignore flag with pip command

Comment: I am not sure how to do that ? It download package then fails with :  DEPRECATION: Uninstalling a distutils installed project (numpy) has been deprecated and will be removed in a future version. This is due to the fact that uninstalling a distutils project will only partially uninstall the project.
    Uninstalling numpy-1.8.0rc1

Comment: Done !! .. Thanks a lot